# Refresh a checkbox, Selenium 2

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to check a checkbox to type values to an input field.

The field appears when i check the box. So i tried :

```
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.id("Checkbox_input"));
box.click();
sleep(5);
// the input can't be detected
// so it throw a noSuchElement.
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("PaymentAmount_input"));
input.sendKeys("12345");
```

I've already use the isSelected() (right after the `click()`) to verify if it's checked.

```
Assert.assertTrue(box.isSelected());
```

I've found something weird that works.. I write that after the `ePrepayment.click()`;

```
box.submit();
```

It works because `submit()` looks like a refresh, so my input appears, but it doesn't delete all values in the others input.

**Specs**

*`sleep()` method*

```
protected void sleep(int i) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

**Question :**

Is there a better way to do that instead of a nasty `submit()` on a checkbox ?

Thank you, Marco

Answer (score 0):

Share your element HTML if possible. There might be something like `onsubmit` show input field instead of `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep()` method doesn't makes sense, since that is a incorrect use of the the Implicit Waits. A more correct approach would be using Explicit Waits:

```java
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.id("Checkbox_input"));
box.click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElemementLocated(By.id("PaymentAmount_input")));
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("PaymentAmount_input"));
input.sendKeys("12345");
```

Assuming `wait` is already correctly started somewhere like:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
```

Comment: I can't define the `wait` like you did and [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) did. It says : *"The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined"* and it says that i need to write it like : `new WebDriverWait(Object, WebDriver, long);`   

**My bad, i imported the wrong package. I'll try like you said and i bounce you.**

Comment: I started reading the comment and was going to mention it might have to do with the imports, as soon as you get a status let me know.